# Error: ValueError: Lengths must match to compare when trying to filter the dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, filtering

I am so sorry for asking this, but for some reasons, I have spent some minutes figuring this out but I am not getting it.

I have a `dataframe`, something of this nature

```
df

Output:
  TypePro
  ["JJ", "KK"]
  ["JK", "RJ"]
  ["JK"]
  ["JK"]
```

I am trying to filter the `dataframe`:

```
df_JJ_KK = df[df.TypePro == ["JJ", "KK"]]
```

But I get the following error: `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`

Please how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. @jezrael to the rescue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension for filtering:

```
df = df[[x == ["JJ", "KK"] for x in df.TypePro]]
print (df)
    TypePro
0  [JJ, KK]
```

Or compare `tuple`s:

```
df = df[df.TypePro.map(tuple) == tuple(["JJ", "KK"])]
```